# gcc -funswitch-loops and -O3

Tags: loops, gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I'm interested in the loop unswitching optimization option `-funswitch-loops` to GCC, in particular what actually enables it. According to the [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html):

> The following options control optimizations that may improve performance, but are not enabled by any `-O` options. This section includes experimental options that may produce broken code.
>
> ...
>
> `-funswitch-loops`
>
> Move branches with loop invariant conditions out of the loop, with duplicates of the loop on both branches (modified according to result of the condition).
>
> Enabled by `-fprofile-use` and `-fauto-profile`.

So if I'm not already using `-fprofile-use` or `-fauto-profile`, it seems that I have to explicitly add `-funswitch-loops` to my list of compiler flags in order to activate loop unswitching. Fair enough. Though elsewhere in the same [documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), we find

> `-O3`
>
> Optimize yet more. `-O3` turns on all optimizations specified by `-O2` and also turns on the following optimization flags:
>
> ...
>
> `-funswitch-loops`
>
> ...

So the documentation seems to claims that `-funswitch-loops` is switched on by `-O3`, but also that it is *not* turned on by *any* of the `-O` options. Which one is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can compile with `-v -Q` to see a list of all the optimization options that are in effect.  With `-v -Q -O3` on gcc 10.2, I see `-funswitch-loops` is included.

So its listing under "not enabled by any `-O` options" is apparently an error.  You could report it as a documentation bug.